# What is the proper endpoint for HDP3.1 Atlas REST API?

Tags: hdp, apache-atlas

Using Atlas v1.1 with HDP 3.1 and appear unable to access the api endpoint for making requests related to relationship characteristics. From the docs ([here](https://github.com/venkatra/atlas-v2/wiki#rest-endpoint) (for API access) and [here](https://atlas.apache.org/1.1.0/api/v2/resource_RelationshipREST.html) (for specific endpoint)), I would think to do something like...

```sh
[hph_etl@HW03 ~]$ curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' "http://hw03.co.local:21000/api/atlas/v2/relationship"


* About to connect() to hw03.co.local port 21000 (#0)
*   Trying 172.18.4.48...
* Connected to hw03.co.local (172.18.4.48) port 21000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /api/atlas/v2/relationship HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: hw03.co.local:21000
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 01:55:43 GMT
< Set-Cookie: ATLASSESSIONID=xxxxxx;Path=/;HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.3.14.v20161028)
<
* Connection #0 to host hw03.co.local left intact
There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID bfb6e6b45490d83a).[
```

to test for the endpoint, but it produces the error shown above. Yet, this is not the case for the `types` endpoint, eg.

```sh
[hph_etl@HW03 ~]$ curl -u admin:admin -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'pplication/json' "http://hw03.co.local:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs"

<whole bunch of output>
```

which appears to work fine. Not sure what is going on here. Anyone with more Atlas (or REST) experience have any debugging suggestions or fixes?

Comment: I believe you have some keys and stuff in your post that you may want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From asking the apache-atlas user mailing list as well as looking into more docs, found that the proper endpoint is not just

```sh
http://atlas-host-server/v2/<specific/api/endpoint>
```

but rather

```sh
http://atlas-host-server/api/atlas/v2/<specific/api/endpoint>
```

So for creating a relationship between entities, you would do something like...

```sh
curl -vv -u admin:admin -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \
   "end1": { \
     "guid": "2ddcda5b-2489-4636-a9ab-12b199c02422" \
   }, \
   "end2": { \
     "guid": "a33f45de-13d0-4a30-9df7-b0e02eb0dfd5" \
   }, \
   "typeName": "<some AtlasRelationshipDef>" \
 }' 'http://HW03.co.local:21000/api/atlas/v2/relationship'
```

Got the information to use `/api/atlas/` from a pdf downloadable from the apache-atlas official site, but could not find it to link here now (just goes to show how oddly hard that critical piece of info is to find).